# store value from data file in variable gnuplot using dummy plot

Tags: plot, gnuplot

This question is related to this one:
[store commented value from data file in gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28987654/store-commented-value-from-data-file-in-gnuplot)

I formatted now every single data file that it looks like:

```
    1.0  0.01

    0.2  0.0163  0.0000125
    0.4  0.0275  0.0001256
```

Then I tried to read the first line and store it into variables in this way:

```
set term push
set term unknown    
plot dataFile every ::0::0 using (a=$0):(b=$1)
set term pop
```

But this is not working as it should, why? The rest of the file I plot as follows:

```
plot dataFile every ::1 using 1:2:3 with errorbars lt 1 linecolor "red",f(a,b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Column counting starts at 1, the zeroth column is the row number. And you must also restrict to the first block (note the three colons). Try

```
plot dataFile every :::0::0 using (a=$1):(b=$2)
```

Alternatively you can use `stats` in a similar way:

```
stats dataFile every :::0::0 using 1:2
a = STATS_min_x
b = STATS_min_y
```

Comment: Thank you! it works now. but it gives me some warnings like `empty x range [0:0], adjusting to [-1:1]` or `empty y range [2:2], adjusting to [1.98:2.02]`. it does not seem like the influence the plot, but where do they come from? or what has to be fixed?

Comment: You can ignore that, it is a normal warning when plotting a single point.